# ElasticSearch / Nest search with synonyms, plural and mispellings

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to do a search that implements the following items.

Right now I have implemented all of this through regex and it is far from covering everything and I would like to know how much I could use ElasticSearch for this instead:

- Synonyms

  My understanding is that this is implemented when the index is created.

  indexSettings.Analysis.TokenFilters.Add("synonym", new SynonymTokenFilter { Synonyms = new[] { "tire => tyre", "aluminum => aluminium" }, IgnoreCase = true, Tokenizer = "whitespace" });

  but do I need to include the plurals as well? or,
- Singular words (shoes and shoe should be an identical match)

  does that mean that I need to put 'shoes' in the synonym list? or is there another way?
- Small misspellings, substitutions and omissions should be allowed

  so that 'automobile', 'automoble' or 'automoblie' would match. I don't know if this is even possible.
- Ignore all stop words

  right now I'm removing all the 'the', 'this', 'my', etc through regex

All my search terms are plain English words and numbers; nothing else is allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of this is possible through **[configuring/writing a custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html)** within Elasticsearch. To answer each question in turn:

> Synonyms

Synonyms can be applied at either index time, search time or both. There are tradeoffs to consider in whichever approach you choose

- Applying synonyms at index time will result in faster search compared to applying at search time, at the cost of more disk space, indexing throughput and ease and flexibility of adding/removing existing synonyms
- Applying synonyms at search time allows for greater flexibility at the expense of search speed.

Also need to consider the size of the synonyms list and how frequently, if ever, it changes. I would consider trying both and deciding which works best for your scenario and requirements.

> Singular words (shoes and shoe should be an identical match)

You may consider using [stemming](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stemming.html) to reduce plural and singular words to their root form, using an algorithmic or dictionary based stemmer. Perhaps start with the [English Snowball stemmer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-tokenfilter.html) and see how it works for you.

You should also consider whether you need to also index the original word form e.g. should exact word matches rank higher than stemmed words on their root form?

> Small misspellings, substitutions and omissions should be allowed

Consider using queries that can utilize [fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzziness.html) to handle typos and misspellings. If there are spelling errors in the index data, consider some form of sanitization before indexing. As per all data stores, Garbage In, Garbage Out :)

> Ignore all stop words

Use an [English Stop token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) to remove stop words.

Putting all of this together, an example analyzer might look like

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Settings(s => s
            .Analysis(a => a
                .TokenFilters(t => t
                    .Stop("my_stop", st => st
                        .StopWords("_english_", "i've")
                        .RemoveTrailing()
                    )
                    .Synonym("my_synonym", st => st
                        .Synonyms(
                            "dap, sneaker, pump, trainer",
                            "soccer => football"
                        )
                    )
                    .Snowball("my_snowball", st => st
                        .Language(SnowballLanguage.English)
                    )
                )
                .Analyzers(an => an
                    .Custom("my_analyzer", ca => ca
                        .Tokenizer("standard")
                        .Filters(
                            "lowercase",
                            "my_stop",
                            "my_snowball",
                            "my_synonym"
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Message>(mm => mm
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(t => t
                        .Name(n => n.Content)
                        .Analyzer("my_analyzer")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    client.Analyze(a => a
        .Index(defaultIndex)
        .Field<Message>(f => f.Content)
        .Text("Loving those Billy! Them is the maddest soccer trainers I've ever seen!")
    );
}

public class Message
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

`my_analyzer` produces the following tokens for above

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "love",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "those",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "billi",
      "start_offset" : 13,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "them",
      "start_offset" : 20,
      "end_offset" : 24,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "maddest",
      "start_offset" : 32,
      "end_offset" : 39,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 6
    },
    {
      "token" : "football",
      "start_offset" : 40,
      "end_offset" : 46,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 7
    },
    {
      "token" : "trainer",
      "start_offset" : 47,
      "end_offset" : 55,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 8
    },
    {
      "token" : "dap",
      "start_offset" : 47,
      "end_offset" : 55,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 8
    },
    {
      "token" : "sneaker",
      "start_offset" : 47,
      "end_offset" : 55,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 8
    },
    {
      "token" : "pump",
      "start_offset" : 47,
      "end_offset" : 55,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 8
    },
    {
      "token" : "ever",
      "start_offset" : 61,
      "end_offset" : 65,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 10
    },
    {
      "token" : "seen",
      "start_offset" : 66,
      "end_offset" : 70,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 11
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Russ, you have no idea how helpful this is! (I may come back here with related questions :))